# Notify all EC2 instances running in ASG

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, microservices, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I've a microservice application that has multiple instances running in ASG. All these applications maintains some internal state. This application exposes Actuator endpoints to refresh it's state. I've some applications which are running on-prem. The scenario is, On some event, I want to call those Actuator endpoints of applications running in AWS to refresh their state. The problem is, If I call LoadBalanced url, then call would go to only one instance. So, I'm thinking of below solutions.

1. Use SQS and let on-prem ap publish and AWS app consume that message. But here also, only one instance will receive the message.
2. Use SNS but listeners are http/s based so URL would remain same so I think only one instance would receive the message. (AFAIK)

Any other solution? Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: You could use a Lambda invoked from an API gateway that lives in the VPC and first lists all instances in the ASG and then connects to each instance and delivers the payload (requires you to set up the correct security groups though).

Answer (score 2):

> Use SNS but listeners are http/s based so URL would remain same so I
> think only one instance would receive the message. (AFAIK)

When using SNS each server would subscribe to the SNS topic, and when each server subscribes it would provide SNS with its direct HTTP(s) URL (not the load balancer URL). When SNS receives a message it would send it to each server that is currently subscribed. I'm not sure SNS will submit the request to the actuator endpoint in the correct format that your application needs though.

Answer (score 0):

There are likely several solutions you could consider, including ones that won't require a code change.  Such as establishing a VPN connection between your on-premise applications and the VPC that contains your ASGs, which would allow you to invoke each machine's refresh endpoint by it's unique private ip address.

However, more simply, [if you're using an AWS Classic ELB or ALB, than repeated calls to the load balancer url should hit each machine running your application if enough calls to the refresh endpoint are made.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html)

Although this may not meet your use case, say if you must strictly limit refresh calls to 1 time per endpoint.  You'd have to experiment with your software and the load balancer's round-robin behavior.